# When does controller helper loaded in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I defined a module variable in a controller's helper module

```
module MyControllerHelper
    @container = {}
    def create(id)
       @container[id] = SomeClass.new
    end
end
```

I found that after some request, `@container` became empty.
So I guess maybe `MyControllerHelper` is loaded somewhere more than once.
Is that true?

If that's true, where is the best place to save `SomeClass` instances?

Comment: What does SomeClass contain exactly? Do you need to use the same instance everywhere (=singleton)?

Answer (score 0):

A controller is instantiated once per request, and then destroyed.
If you want to persist data between requests, use the `session` hash.

Comment: what if I want to persist data throughout the application life?

Comment: save it in the database, obviously

Comment: the data suppose to be deleted when my rails app is down, so just it keep in memory will be fine and results better performance. I change `@container` to a global variable and i works fine.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but note that if you use a global variable it will be shared across all the sessions.

Comment: You could use @@container (note two @@'s) - it's called class variable. AFAIK it will persist assigned data between requests.

Comment: @UģisOzols, I got an error `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized class variable @@container in MyControllerHelper)` when open every page